# Child process is killed when windows service is stopped

Tags: c#, windows-services, nssm

I have a small C# console app that monitors some configured process(es)/app(s), these are also C# console apps, and keep them running so it starts them if they crashed. It works well if I run this monitor console app by executing exe file (in interactive mode). However if I install this app as a windows service using NSSM, the monitored process(es) are killed when the service is stopped which is not what I want.

The minimum code to reproduce (this code starts the child process only once and does not monitor it at all):

Monitoring app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = "..\\..\\..\\TestApp\\bin\\debug\\TestApp.exe";            

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        Console.WriteLine("Process started");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Monitored app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("running...");

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way how to keep these child process(es) running after windows service is stopped?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSSM has a configuration option which does not kill the entire process tree when stopping the service.

You can configure this in the UI with `nssm.exe edit "my service name"` or directly with `nssm.exe set "my service name" AppKillProcessTree 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` for the "child" processes.  This will execute the process from the shell as a separate/independent process.

Comment: I have tried that now but with no success :( (I also have tried CreateNoWindow property and few others)